# File.Exists function not working in Windows8 or higher

Tags: .net, file, windows-8, windows-10-desktop

1. The file exists function always return false even file exists.
2. I tried to copy file path n pasted in run and tried to open manually, it failed even File exists physically (Win7 works fine, Win8 or higher issue)
3. Tried several solutions from the internet.

```
    string FilePath = @"‪D:\Test\alllllllllthe Data.docx";
    if (File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        string FileContent = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
```

`}`

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct, I am running Windows 10 1703 and just tested this.  Works just fine.

Comment: @JasonH - follow these steps to reproduce it.
1. Create folder in D/E drive eg: D:
2. Create folder under it eg: D:\Test
3. Create/Place file eg: D:\Test\myFile.docx
4. Right click file >> Property >> Security tab >> Object Name >> Copy whole file path
5. Press Win+R paste that path >> Enter

Comment: I tried serval time, 8/10 times its easily reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Right I will be honest as to not understanding what changed that is causing this because you are correct:

```
string filePath = @"D:\Folder\somefile.txt";
File.Exists(filePath) == TRUE // this is not happening
```

I took this a step further and did:

```
try
{
    var filePath = Path.GetFullPath("E:\\Folder\\somefile.txt");
    File.OpenRead(filePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

The exception that is thrown is:
`NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.`

This does work so give this a go:

```
var filePath = Path.GetFullPath("D:\\Folder\\somefile.txt");
File.Exists(filePath) == TRUE // this does work
```

Alternatively, you could use this as well:

```
var path = @"D:\Folder";
var fileName = "somefile.txt";
var filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
File.Exists(filePath) == TRUE // this does work
```

Comment: Basically, file operation are giving me same error **The given path's format is not supported**

Comment: Added an Alternative option as well

Comment: I worked around the issue, there is extra character ? in the path start which is invisible. even wen i paste in Win+r or notepad. extra character is hidden
so I came up with the solution.

private string TrimInvalidChars(string FileFullPath)
{
 int index = FileFullPath.IndexOf(":");
        if (index > 0)
        {
         FileFullPath = FileFullPath.Substring(index - 1);
        } 
 return FileFullPath;
}

Comment: Does the problem only occur when you copy and paste the file path into the source code?